# Why are flow sealed object type properties not checked in conditionals

Tags: javascript, flowtype

What is the reason that sealed object properties are not checked in conditionals?

For example:

```
// Create a sealed object type
const o = {
  Foo: 'Foo',
};

// Access a non-existent property
// Reports an Error
const fooz = o.Fooz;

// Conditional with non-existent property
// Does not report an error
if (o.Fooz === undefined) {}
```

Just to clarify - this is a [Flow sealed object](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-sealed-objects)

Comment: That is *not* a sealed object. You want `const o = Object.seal({Foo: 'Foo'});` or possibly `Object.freeze...`

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith, I should clarify - I believe this is a sealed object from Flow's perspective. Looking at the docs (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-sealed-objects) it reads "When you create an object with its properties, you create a sealed object type in Flow."

Comment: Unfortunate that they chose that term since it already has another meaning in JavaScript. As for your question, I can't find anything on this in the Flow documentation. Likely possibilities: statically analyzing a highly dynamic language is hard and the compiler can't resolve this case in a reasonable amount of time or at all, or it's a concession to the popularity of that pattern in existing code, or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question as a [Flow issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5477). I received a reply:

> Non-existence is not an error within a conditional expression. See the
>   comment from [the source](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/c9131da361ab03e64227d870ec113bd030993a3e/src/typing/statement.ml#L4453-L4456).

The source comment reads:

> Conditional expressions are checked like expressions, except that
>   property accesses are provisionally allowed even when such properties
>   do not exist. This accommodates the common JavaScript idiom of testing
>   for the existence of a property before using that property.